# Use Regular Expression inside URL for API call

Tags: regex, string

I am calling one API that takes phone number as an input and provide response matching that phone number.

URL ends with this: 
https://www.something.com/something&api_key=xxxx&sig=xxxx+"&%24filter=endswith(MobilePhone%2c'1234512345')

If in server mobile number is saved in same format as specified in url, that time it is giving me correct response.

**But the problem is:** If in server phone number is saved in different format like 12-3451-2345(with hyphen) or 12 3451 2345(with space), that time it is giving me empty response.

I tried using regular expression and wild card character in the above url, so that even if the hyphen and spaces are present in phone number in server, it should give me the correct response. But it didn't work. Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there API documentation available? Do you have any more information on that API? Perhaps it has other criteria apart from `endswith(`.

Comment: Possible dirty workaround: If only types of phone formats present are with hyphens, spaces and without delimiters, and delimiters are always in the same locations, you could always do three requests. I.e. each time user enters 1234512345, query your API using that, then 12-3451-2345 and then 12 3451 2345. Then use whichever response that was not empty.

Comment: It's a server part of control. You can't do anything, exept working with provided services. So in this case either server have to match all formats of phone numbers itself or it have to require only one format to be approved otherwise server side not implemented correctly

Comment: @user5226582: thank you for your response. yes i thought of it but its not a good idea as sometimes i will be sending 200 numbers to get their response. so 200*3=600 calls of API. :|

Comment: @Beloo yes right. but i was thinking if there is any way that we can use like some wild card character like '*' , '%'. for example :
12%3451%2345. so it will give response if there is space or hyphen or no-space between them.

Comment: @IshanKhanduja regarding your last comment - it depends on how the API is implemented. There's no way to tell how it parses that string. That's why I asked about API documentation.